# Ways to check whether your predictors are even correlated with their label?

Tags: data, correlation, pca, tsne

I scraped a dataset of pre-match data in a video game and am trying to classify them by outcome, i.e. wins v. losses. The models I've tried so far have poor accuracy of around 50%, so I'm thinking that my data's X and Y might be poorly correlated to begin with - are there ways to investigate this? So far I've tried PCA + TSNE and labeled them by outcome to see if there's obvious clustering, and will probably look at R^2 (but this statistic would be relatively unuseful if the relationship is nonlinear, right?). Are there other things worth trying? And how do you know when you've done your due diligence and should just scrape a different dataset?

Comment: Show us your dataset, please. // For contests between humans, an [Elo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) ranking is usually the appropriate way to predict the outcome of some future PvP contest.